# jQuery animations in each loop all run at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 4 elements that I am trying to animate up, but instead of each element animating up all elements are animated at once. I even tried putting a delay on the animation and it still does not work.

```js
(function($){
  var options_position = $('#options').offset().top;
  var options_completed = false;
  var options_delay = 1000;
  //secondary options fire event to ascend pictures
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = options_position;

    if((y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) && !options_completed) {
      options_completed = true;

      $('#options-secondary .option').each(function(){
        $(this).animate({
          top: '-=160'
        },options_delay,function(){}).delay( 800 );
        //window.setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
      });
      options_delay = options_delay + 600;
      console.log(options_delay);
      console.log(options_completed);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
<section id="options-secondary">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option" id="plans">
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option" id="broker">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Not sure how to make each element animate one after the other at not all at once.

Comment: you can for example use the index of the item to delay the actions proportionally, like: `.each(function(index){ $(this).delay(options_delay * index).animate( /* etc */ ); })`. The index starts at 0 so there will be no delay for the first (note that delay must be chained before the animation)

Comment: So delay should always go first?

Comment: before the action you want to delay, at least

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to invoke one at a time

```js
(function($){
 var options_position = $('#options').offset().top;
 var options_completed = false;
 var options_delay = 1000;
 //secondary options fire event to ascend pictures
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
  var scroll_pos_test = options_position;

  if((y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) && !options_completed) {
   options_completed = true;
oneByOne(0);
        
          function oneByOne(i) {
            $("#options-secondary .option")
              .eq(i)
              .animate(
                {
                  top: '-=160px'
                },
                function() {
                  if (i < 4) {
                    oneByOne(i + 1);
                  }
                }
              );
          }
 
         options_delay = options_delay + 600;
         console.log(options_delay);
         console.log(options_completed);
     }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.option {
position:relative;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
<section id="options-secondary">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option" id="plans">
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option" id="broker">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="copy align-middle option">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket rotate-360-hover" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut nunc urna.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```